# How to make GCC not generate .idata section?

Tags: gcc, ld, portable-executable

How to make GCC not generate .idata section ?
Or how do I merge idata section into rdata section ?

Answer (score 0):

dont use any imports.. if you dont have idate you could eventually wipe it out in hex-editor.. but you would not have imports then..

if you would alone wnat to move it to rdata it might be possible (by copying its contents into rdata) and setting some fields in pe header..but im not 100% sure...

generally as i said it would beed steps like reserving some space in rdata, copying idata contents to it, setting apropriate fields in pe header... but this is heavy hack